# REGEXP_SUBSTR - multiple matches from XML code

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

i have this result from a select (CLOB data) entire code of record:

```
<Job jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" release="5.3.18.269"><Node name="Start" jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" id="1" isJobRoot="true" captionOfDesc="{R001145}" xCoord="20" yCoord="20" endNodeIdLinked="5" type="0"/><Node name="ETL_JOB_TABLES" jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" id="2" codActivity="ETL_JOB_DATA" captionOfDesc="{C006939}" xCoord="135" yCoord="1" endNodeIdLinked="5" type="1" desc0="Job ETL per anagrafiche 1" desc1="ETL job for tables 1"><Param name="raccolta" caption="C000264" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="SEGMENT2022_M" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="false" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="RAC" parameterType="ANA"/><Param name="scenarioPeriodoOriginarioList" caption="C003374" className="[Lit.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario;" isMandatory="true" isArray="true" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario" inputType="codMultiDesc" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="true" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="SCE_ORIG_PER" parameterType="ANA"/>
<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="ANA_AZ_CONS_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
</Node><Node name="ETL_JOB_TABLES" jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" id="3" codActivity="ETL_JOB_DATA" captionOfDesc="{C006939}" xCoord="340" yCoord="1" endNodeIdLinked="5" type="1" desc0="Job ETL per anagrafiche 2" desc1="ETL job for tables 2"><Param name="raccolta" caption="C000264" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="SEGMENT2022_M" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="false" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="RAC" parameterType="ANA"/><Param name="scenarioPeriodoOriginarioList" caption="C003374" className="[Lit.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario;" isMandatory="true" isArray="true" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario" inputType="codMultiDesc" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="true" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="SCE_ORIG_PER" parameterType="ANA"/>
<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="AZI_PROCESSO_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
</Node><Node name="ETL_JOB_TABLES" jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" id="4" codActivity="ETL_JOB_DATA" captionOfDesc="{C006939}" xCoord="545" yCoord="1" endNodeIdLinked="5" type="1" desc0="Job ETL per anagrafiche 3" desc1="ETL job for tables 3"><Param name="raccolta" caption="C000264" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.Raccolta" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="SEGMENT2022_M" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="false" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="RAC" parameterType="ANA"/><Param name="scenarioPeriodoOriginarioList" caption="C003374" className="[Lit.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario;" isMandatory="true" isArray="true" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.ScenarioPeriodoOriginario" inputType="codMultiDesc" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="true" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="SCE_ORIG_PER" parameterType="ANA"/>
<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="CAMBI_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
</Node><Node name="End" jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" id="5" captionOfDesc="{R001146}" startNodeIdLinked="1" type="2"/><Edge jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" from="1" to="2"/><Edge jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" from="2" to="3"/><Edge jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" from="3" to="4"/><Edge jobId="ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL" from="4" to="5"/></Job>
```

the result i expect with REGEXP_SUBSTR is:

```
ANA_AZ_CONS_MA
AZI_PROCESSO_MA
CAMBI_MA
```

I try with this select but i can't get the result i expect, is it possible to get the result as i said before or am i dreaming?:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (JOB_GRAPH, 'value="([^\"]+)') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM JOB_STRUCTURE WHERE JOB_ID = 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL'
```

Thanks

Comment: On Oracle 19C the solutions, don't work :( Result are blank or NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. Use a proper parser:

```
SELECT x.value
FROM   job_structure j
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/Param'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( j.job_graph )
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@value'
       ) x
WHERE  job_id = 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL';
```

or:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY('/Param/@value' PASSING XMLTYPE(job_graph) RETURNING CONTENT)
         AS value
FROM   job_structure
WHERE  job_id = 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB_STRUCTURE (
  job_id    VARCHAR2(50),
  job_graph CLOB
);

INSERT INTO job_structure (job_id, job_graph)
  SELECT 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL', '<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="ANA_AZ_CONS_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL', '<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="AZI_PROCESSO_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL', '<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="CAMBI_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| ANA_AZ_CONS_MA |
| AZI_PROCESSO_MA |
| CAMBI_MA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j-bGcFj0)

---

#### Update

If the values are all contained in the same row then you do not have well-formed XML as you only have a fragment. What you need to do to make it well-formed is to wrap it in a element so that there is a single root:

So, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB_STRUCTURE (
  job_id    VARCHAR2(50),
  job_graph CLOB
);

INSERT INTO job_structure (job_id, job_graph)
  SELECT 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL',
         '<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="ANA_AZ_CONS_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
          <Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="AZI_PROCESSO_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
          <Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="CAMBI_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>' FROM DUAL;
```

You can then use:

```
SELECT x.value
FROM   job_structure j
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         'root/Param'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<root>' || j.job_graph || '</root>' )
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@value'
       ) x
WHERE  job_id = 'ANAGRAFICHE_MANAGERIAL';
```

Which outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| ANA_AZ_CONS_MA |
| AZI_PROCESSO_MA |
| CAMBI_MA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNdlyq-i)

Comment: Hi, thanks for try to solve my problem but in first case i have, under VALUE, (null) and in the second case, VALUE, blank... Thanks you so much!

Comment: @GabrielAlejandroLopez Please provide a [MRE] that can replicate the issue. You can see from the fiddle linked in the answer and an [Oracle 18 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YpzMM3Iw) that it does not output null or blank values for your sample data and without a way to replicate the issue we cannot help.

Comment: The problem is that all XML code is contained in one record, not 3 like you did

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify

Comment: Ok, all tags before are 
<Job>
 <Node>
   <Param> ...value...

Comment: `<Job jobId=...
<Node name...
<Param name="job" caption="C003886" className="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" isMandatory="true" isArray="false" componentClass="it.grupposervizi.easy.ef.base.etl.Job" inputType="codMultiDesc" value="ANA_AZ_CONS_MA" isEnabled="true" hasDisplayValues="true" enableAllValuesVisible="false" isEnabledOnlyAllValues="false" dim="JOB"/>
</Node>
</Job>`

Comment: After Update, always Column Value are blank :-( i don't understand :-(

Comment: @GabrielAlejandroLopez Please provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNdlyq-i) that contains an example of your data. It is impossible to guess what your structure is and to then get told that that it is something different; either provide some representative data or we won't be able to help debug the issue.

Comment: Sure: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/hafLUYF6)

Comment: @GabrielAlejandroLopez Use the correct XPATH [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/18u76tyD)

Comment: Hi, correct XPATH to work as i want: '/Job/Node/Param[@name="job"]'... Thanks for all